# Correct user profile path via ntuser.dat using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, profile

I need to modify an existing script that was created (before my time) to modify users profile paths in the registry via their ntuser.dat file. The file must be copied locally, modified and then copied back to the server. The servers are terminal servers (RDS now) used in our Citrix solution. I need to have the script correct the user shell folders and the shell folders (the new settings are in the script) in the registry and also make sure they are pointed to the correct home directory via homeDirectory (currently the script points to the TS home directory via TerminalServicesHomeDirectory). A GPO sets the APPDATA and the HOMESHARE. The log file spits out the following when I run it:

```
2017-12-22 15:23:25 --- Group name to use is test_testusers
2017-12-22 15:23:25 --- Test1script does not have a homeDirectory attribute in AD
2017-12-22 15:23:25 --- Test2script does not have a homeDirectory attribute in AD
2017-12-22 15:23:25 --- Closing log File.
```

The group name is gathered from a prompt. This script needs to be able to run on the OU gathered from the input prompt. Now for the script:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Correct profile path.

.DESCRIPTION
  This script is used to correct the registry entries for users 
  that were migrated to other servers, to now use relative
  path.

.OUTPUTS
  Log file stored in the current folder.

#>

Function Invoke-Logging
{
<#  
    DESCRIPTION
    -----------
    This function is used to create and update the Log File.    

DEPENDENCIES
------------               
$Script:Log - This parameter is used to declare the log file path,
              if this parameter is left blank errors will be  thrown.  

#>
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Create')]
param
(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Msg,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Create')]
    [Switch]
    $Create,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NewLine')]
    [Switch]
    $NewLine,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Append')]
    [Switch]
    $Append,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Break')]
    [Switch]
    $Break,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveLast')]
    [Switch]
    $RemoveLast
)

Begin
{
    [String]$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"
    [String]$str = "$TimeStamp --- $Msg"
}

Process
{
    If($Create)
    {

        New-Item $Script:LogPathName -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
    }
    ElseIf($NewLine)
    {
        $str = ""
    }
    ElseIf($Break)
    {
        $str = "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    }
    ElseIf($RemoveLast)
    {
        #Remove the last line by reading all but the last line in to an update.
        $LogContent = Get-Content $Script:LogPathName
        New-Item $Script:LogPathName -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
        $Str = $LogContent[0..($LogContent.length-2)]
    }
    #Add Content to the log
    Add-Content -Path $Script:LogPathName -Value $Str

    #if script is in debug mode it will write to the log and the screen
    If($Script:Debug){Write-Host $str}
    } 
}

Function Get-Domains
{
<#  
    DESCRIPTION
    -----------
    This function is used to find the DN of a group in AD.  

    DEPENDENCIES
    ------------            
$Script:Domains - This variable stores the domains in the current environment.  

#>

Process
{
    $ForestDomains = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Domains

    ForEach($Domain in $ForestDomains)
    {
        $Script:Domains += "DC=$($Domain.Name.Replace(".", ",DC="))"
        }
    }
}

Function Get-ADObjectDn
{
<#  
DESCRIPTION
-----------
This function is used to find the DN of a group in AD.  

DEPENDENCIES
------------            
None  

#>
Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $objectName
)


[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult]$discoveredObject

Foreach ($keyDomain in $Domains)
{
    [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$dirEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$keyDomain")
    [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$dirSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dirEntry, "(&(objectCategory=group)(|(sAMAccountName=$objectName)(Name=$objectName)))")
    $dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ADsPath") | Out-Null        
    $discoveredObject = $dirSearch.FindOne()
    If ($discoveredObject -ne $null)
    {
        $adsPath = $discoveredObject.Properties["adspath"][0].ToString()
        $dirSearch.Dispose()
        $dirEntry.Dispose()
        Return $adsPath
    }
    $dirSearch.Dispose()
    $dirEntry.Dispose()
    }
    Return $null
}

Function Get-ADGroupMembers
{
<#  
DESCRIPTION
-----------
This function is used to return all users and their TerminalServicesHomeDirectory
of a specified group.   

DEPENDENCIES
------------              
None  

#>

Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $objectDN
)

[String]$TSHome
$UserData = @()
[String]$dsFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:=$($objectDN.Replace(' LDAP://',''))))"
[String]$domainBase = $objectDN.Substring($objectDN.IndexOf("DC="))
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$deBase = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$domainBase")
[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$dirSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($deBase)
$dirSearch.Filter = $dsFilter
$dirSearch.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$dirSearch.PageSize = 1000
$dirSearch.CacheResults = $false
$dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName") | Out-Null
[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection]$results = $dirSearch.FindAll()

Foreach ($Member in $results)
{
    [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$deUser = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Member.Properties["adspath"][0].ToString())
    $TSHome = $deUser.TerminalServicesHomeDirectory

    If($TSHome.GetType() -eq [String])
    {
        $UserData += @{Name = $deUser.sAMAccountName.Value;Path = $TSHome}
    }Else
    {
        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "$($deUser.sAMAccountName.Value) does not have a TerminalServicesHomeDirectory attribute in AD"
    }

}

$results.Dispose()
$dirSearch.Dispose()
$deBase.Dispose()
return $UserData
}

Function Fix-NTUSER
{
<#  
DESCRIPTION
-----------
This function will copy the ntuser.dat file locally, load it to the registry,
make the updates and then copy it back to the server after renaming the exiting
file on the server. 

DEPENDENCIES
------------

None  

#>
param
(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Path,
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $UserName
)

Begin
{
    $ProfileReg = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('(\\\\([\w]+\.?)+\\[\w\d\.]+\$?)', 'ignorecase')
    $Path = "$Path\UPM\RDS\UPM_Profile\ntuser.dat"
    $LocalPath = "$Script:CurrentDirectory\$UserName\$UserName.dat"
}

Process
{

    If(Test-Path $Path)
    {
        Try
        {
        New-Item "$Script:CurrentDirectory\$UserName" -Type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Copying $Path"
        Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $LocalPath -Force
        C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe load "hku\$UserName" $LocalPath | Out-Null

            ForEach($KeyPath in $RegKeys.Keys)
            {
                If (Test-Path HKU:\$UserName\$KeyPath)
                {
                    ForEach($Key in $RegKeys.Item($KeyPath))
                    {
                        $CurrentValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKU:\$UserName\$KeyPath).$Key
                        If($ProfileReg.IsMatch($CurrentValue))
                        {
                            Set-ItemProperty -Path HKU:\$UserName\$KeyPath -Name $Key -Value $ProfileReg.Replace($CurrentValue, '%HOMESHARE%')
                            Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Updated HKEY_USERS\$UserName\$KeyPath\$Key From $CurrentValue To $($ProfileReg.Replace($CurrentValue, '%HOMESHARE%'))"
                        }Else
                        {
                            Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Nothing to update for HKEY_USERS\$UserName\$KeyPath\$Key $CurrentValue"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe unload "hku\$UserName" | Out-Null

        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Renaming current ntuser.dat"
        Move-Item -Path $Path -Destination "$Path.old_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMMdd_HHmm")"

        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Copying good ntuser.dat to original location"
        Copy-Item -Path $LocalPath -Destination $Path

        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Cleaning up local files"
        Remove-Item "$Script:CurrentDirectory\$UserName" -Force -Recurse

        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Completed processing registry updates for $UserName"
        }Catch
        {
            If(Test-Path HKU:\$UserName){C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe unload "hku\$UserName" | Out-Null}
            Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
        }
    }Else
    {
        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "$Path Not found"
    }
} 
}


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

[String]$Script:LogName = "Fix-SBCPath_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMMdd_HHmm").log"
[String]$Script:CurrentDirectory = Split-Path $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
[String]$Script:LogFolder = $CurrentDirectory
[String]$Script:LogPathName = "$LogFolder\$LogName"
[String]$Script:ScriptName = "Fix-SBCPath"
[String]$Script:Version = "1.0"
[Boolean]$Script:Debug = $false
[String[]]$Script:Domains = @()
[Int]$CurrentUser = 0
[HashTable]$RegKeys = @{}
$RegKeys.Add('Volatile Environment', @('APPDATA', 'HOMESHARE'))
$RegKeys.Add('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell 
Folders', @('{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}', '{56784854-C6CB-462B-
8169-88E350ACB882}', 
'{7D1D3A04-DEBB-4115-95CF-2F29DA2920DA}', '{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}', 'Administrative Tools',
'AppData', 'Desktop', 'Favorites', 'My Music', 'My Pictures', 'My Video', 'Personal', 'Programs', 'Start Menu', 'Startup'))
$RegKeys.Add('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', @('{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}', '{56784854-C6CB-462B-8169-88E350ACB882}', 
'{7D1D3A04-DEBB-4115-95CF-2F29DA2920DA}', '{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}', 'Administrative Tools',
'AppData', 'Desktop', 'Favorites', 'My Music', 'My Pictures', 'My Video', 'Personal', 'Programs', 'Start Menu', 'Startup'))


Invoke-Logging -Create -Msg "$Script:ScriptName Version $Script:Version Log Started."
Invoke-Logging -NewLine

Get-Domains

#Get the group name from the user
$GroupName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the Terminal Services User group to query", "Group Name")

If([String]::IsNullorEmpty($GroupName))
{
Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "User Cancelled input."
Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Closing log File."
Invoke-Logging -NewLine
break
}

Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Group name to use is $GroupName"

[String]$GroupDN = Get-ADObjectDn -objectName $GroupName

If($GroupDN -eq $null)
{
    Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "$GroupName was not found in AD"
}Else
{
#Create a drive for HKEY_USERS to make registry edits as hives are loaded.
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

#Get a collection of users and the paths 
$Users = Get-ADGroupMembers -objectDN $GroupDN

ForEach($User in $Users)
{
    $CurrentUser += 1
    If($user.Path -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Correcting Users NTUSER.DAT Files" -status "Correcting $($User.Name)" -percentComplete (($CurrentUser / $Users.count)*100)
        Fix-NTUSER -UserName $User.Name -Path $User.Path
    }
}

Remove-PSDrive -Name HKU
}

Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "Closing log File."
Invoke-Logging -NewLine
```

Update: The script fails on trying to get the ADspath. In the Get-ADObjectDn funciton, the ADspath is set to load its properties. This returns null and that's what causes the script to fail. Is there a better way to get the ADspath properites to load?

Comment: What is the error or behavior that is generated by the above code?

Comment: Why not use GPO to modify the userprofile path?

Comment: We have over 100 organizations and a vigorous and extremely long change management process. To make a long story short, the GPO route is not happening anytime soon.

Comment: The code stops when the homedirectory is not found. It is present but for some reason, I cannot get this script to get or show it.

Comment: Update: The script fails on trying to get the ADspath. In the Get-ADObjectDn funciton, the ADspath is set to load its properties. This returns null and that's what causes the script to fail. Is there a better way to get the ADspath properites to load?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this out with some help. The issued lied here:

```
Foreach ($Member in $results)
{
    [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$deUser = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Member.Properties["adspath"][0].ToString())
    $TSHome = $deUser.homeDirectory

    If($TSHome.GetType() -eq [String])
    {
        $UserData += @{Name = $deUser.sAMAccountName.Value;Path = $TSHome}
    }Else
    {
        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "$($deUser.sAMAccountName.Value) does not have a homeDirectory attribute in AD"
    }

}
```

Specifically here: If($TSHome.GetType() -eq [String])

I am looking for a string when I clearly changed it to a collection here: [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$deUser = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Member.Properties["adspath"][0].ToString())

I simply had to change String to System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection

The end result is this:

```
Foreach ($Member in $results)
{
    [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]$deUser = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Member.Properties["ADspath"][0].ToString())
    $TSHome = $deUser.homeDirectory

    If($TSHome.GetType() -eq [System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection])
    {
        $UserData += @{Name = $deUser.sAMAccountName.Value;Path = $TSHome}
    }Else
    {
        Invoke-Logging -Append -Msg "$($deUser.sAMAccountName.Value) does not have a homeDirectory attribute in AD"
    }

}
```

That change allowed me to set the $TSHome variable and now the script functions correctly!

Thanks for the help and sorry for the convoluted script and explanation.